# Target property of object using array - Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, properties, target

I'm having trouble with this one.

```
//Targeting a property of an object using an array

myArray = ["property0","property1","property2","property3"];

myObject = {};

myObject[myArray[0]] = "value0";
//accepts this line as myObject.property0 = "value0";  

alert(myObject.myArray[0]);  // <-- how can I target this using my Array?
//this fails

// alert(myObject.property0); 
//this works
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same way you set it:

```
alert(myObject[myArray[0]])
```

Comment: Wow. Can't believe the answer was so easy. I was having a headache over this one.  Thanks Alexei!